# Camel route POSTs to service that takes 20+ minutes to respond

Tags: web-services, rest, apache-camel

I have an Apache Camel (version 2.15.3) route that is configured as follows (using a mix of XML and Java DSL):

1. Read a file from one of several folders on an FTP site.

   - Set a header to indicate which folder it was read from.
2. Do some processing and auditing.
3. Synchronously POST to an external REST service (jax-rs 1.1, Glassfish, Java EE 6).

   - The REST service takes a long time to do its job, 20+ minutes.
4. Receive the reply.
5. Do some more processing and auditing.
6. Write the response to one of several folders on an FTP site.

   - Use the header set at the start to know which folder to write to.

This is all configured in a single path of chained routes.

The problem is that the connection to the external REST service will timeout while the service is still processing. The infrastructure is a bit complex (edge servers, load balancers, Glassfish), and regardless I don't think increasing the timeout is the right solution.

How can I implement this route such that I avoid timeouts while still meeting all my requirements to (1) write the response to the appropriate FTP folder, (2) audit the transaction, and (3) meet other transaction/context-specific requirements?

I'm relatively new to Camel and REST, so maybe this is easy, but I don't know what Camel and REST tools and techniques to use.

(Questions and suggestions for improvement are welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it possible to break the two main steps a part and have two asynchronous operations?

I would do as follows.

1. Read a file from one of several folders on an FTP site.
2. Set a header to indicate which folder it was read from.
3. Save the header and file name and other relevant information in a cache. There is a camel component called camel-cache that is relatively easy to setup and you can store key-value or any other objects.
4. Do some processing and auditing. **Asynchronously** POST to an external REST service (jax-rs 1.1, Glassfish, Java EE 6). Note that we are posting asynchronously here.

Step 2.

1. Receive the reply.
2. Lookup the reply identifiers i.e. filename or some other identifier in cache to match the reply and then fetch the header.
3. Do some more processing and auditing.
4. Write the response to one of several folders on an FTP site.

This way, you don't need to wait and processing can take 20 min or longer. You just set your cache values to not expire for say 24h.

Comment: If we post asynchronously, how will Camel receive the reply? Would I implement a REST endpoint on Camel using the [rest component](http://camel.apache.org/rest.html)?

Comment: Yes, you need to expose an REST endpoint to receive the reply. A bit more work, but easier to maintain as you get rid of the timeout and a connection that has to be kept alive for that long.

Comment: @DavidS this is the cache component. http://camel.apache.org/cache.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical asynchronous use case. Can the rest service give you a token id or some unique id immediately after you hit them ?

So that you can have a batch job or some other camel route which will pick up this id from a database/cache and hit the rest service again after 20 minutes.

This is the ideal solution I can think of, if the rest service can provision this.

You are right, waiting for 20 minutes on a synchronous call is a crazy idea. Also what is the estimated size of the file/payload which you are planning to post to the rest service ?

Comment: The file/payload contains a list of records, so size is proportional to the number of items in the list. I expect a typical file to be between 1 and 10MB, but there is no logical limit.

Comment: 10 MB sounds Okay, but it depends on the number of 10 MB files concurrently. Is this 10 MB file going to be just one off every day? or else, consider file streaming, luckily you are using FTP, camel should be able to stream the file line by line !